# Confidence interval for sample mean (possible error in text)

Tags: confidence-interval

I am working through a problem on CI for a sample mean and I cannot get the answer listed in the  text I have. I am wondering if I am missing something or whether the text may be incorrect.

We are given a sample of 10 scores:

```
45,38,52,48,25,39,51,46,55,46
```

I get a mean of 44.5 and SD of 8.68 which is the same as the solutions listed. I also get a standard error of the mean of 2.75 which is the same as the solutions.

However I cannot get the final answer. We are asked to calculate a 95% CI for the mean. When I calculate the margin of error (standard error of the mean * tcritical) I get the answer `2.75*2.262=6.2`. (I choose df= 9). Thus the CI I get is `38.3 - 50.7`.

However, the text says it is `28.35-60.65`. Am I missing something? I would be really grateful for any comments. Thanks.

Comment: I got the same confidence interval that you got.

Comment: It does look as if the text may have added 10 to the margin of error for the mean.  Another, less likely, possibility is that the text is looking at the distribution of the population rather than the mean: 9 of the 10 values are inside the text's interval.

Comment: @Henry. Thank you. Can you say more about your second line, the possibility that it is looking at the distribution of the population?

Comment: @Anne: The text's interval is very wide, so trying to guess the cause raises various possibilities: the fact that it contains almost all of the sample might suggest that it is based on the population distribution rather than the sample mean distribution, though I have not spotted a calculation which leads to its numbers.  Alternatively, the text's interval is $44.5 \pm 16.15$ compared with your $44.5 \pm 6.2$; hence the possibility of a 10 creeping in.  Both of these are speculation.

Comment: Thanks. That is helpful. I also cold not find a calculation that would lead to these numbers. I see now what you mean about the addition of a 10 to the margin of error. I can understand the addition of an extra decimal place but the addition of a 10 seems like a strange error.

Comment: @Henry Would you mind converting your very good comments as a response? The OP could even accept it afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

The answer that your book gives can be computed (almost exactly) from mean +- 1.96 * standard deviation of the population.

```
=AVERAGE(data)    44.5
=STDEV.P(data)     8.237
=1.96 * STDEV     16.144
=44.5 - 16.14     28.356
=44.5 + 16.14     60.644
```

That's the answer that was given to within 0.01.

I am not saying this is right - but I'm pretty sure that's where the author got his/her numbers from. It is not the answer to the question that was asked ("what is the confidence interval of the mean"). I believe your approach to that question was correct, as earlier comments stated.